# MAMP PRO 4 on Windows 10 won't Start

Tags: mamp-pro

I have MAMP PRO 4.0.1 installed on my Windows 10 computer and unfortunately it won't start.

When I open MAMP PRO I get the following error message:

**Error starting services**

**Servers could not be started. Please check server log file for any error messages.**

I checked the `debug.log` file and received the following error message:

```
12/14/2018 2:34:24 PM:::Error:Main Exception:
ServiceStartFailed:<MAMPPRO-Apache>
at MAMPCore.Utility.ServiceHelper.ServiceRunFour(String serviceName, 
HandleRequest request, Server singleServer)
at MAMPCore.Utility.ServicesStartManagerFour.⁬‪‬‎⁬‮‪‎⁪​‍⁯‎‍‭⁫​⁮​‫⁬‎⁯‍‪⁯⁮⁫‍‭‭‎‫‌‬⁫⁭‭⁮‎‮()
at MAMPCore.Utility.ServicesStartManagerFour.‌‌⁪‭‎⁫‍⁪‭‫‮‌‎‏⁮⁭‫⁬‍​‪‎‮⁯‮‎‬‎‫⁯‍‫⁭⁯‎‫‎⁬⁪⁫‮()
at MAMPCore.Utility.ServicesStartManagerFour.‍⁯‪⁬‭‮‌⁪‪⁫‎⁯‭‎‮‌‫‪‏‫‍‌​⁭‏⁯​‫‌‌⁪‭‍‫‏‫‪‎‫‮‮(Object , DoWorkEventArgs )
```

After opening MAMP PRO I also clicking **Stop** in the upper-right doesn't work.

Finally, I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling MAMP PRO and that didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: having the exact same issue https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rkFBWrrFXanbXIaigK1jKBgkI3ou82Yh/view?usp=drivesdk